# mvn liquibase:update results in "Failed to resolve the properties file."

Tags: java, maven, liquibase

When i run `mvn liquibase:update`, i get these on the stdout:

```
[INFO] Executing on Database: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/PROJECT_NAME
INFO 20/09/16 09:41:liquibase: null: null: Successfully acquired change log lock
INFO 20/09/16 09:41:liquibase: null: null: Creating database history table with name: databasechangelog
INFO 20/09/16 09:41:liquibase: null: null: Reading from databasechangelog
INFO 20/09/16 09:41:liquibase: null: null: Reading from databasechangelog
INFO 20/09/16 09:41:liquibase: PROJECT_NAME/src/main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml: PROJECT_NAME/src/main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-1.0.yaml::1::matheus.serpellone: Table PERMISSIONS created
INFO 20/09/16 09:41:liquibase: PROJECT_NAME/src/main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml: PROJECT_NAME/src/main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-1.0.yaml::1::matheus.serpellone: ChangeSet PROJECT_NAME/src/main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-1.0.yaml::1::matheus.serpellone ran successfully in 22ms
INFO 20/09/16 09:41:liquibase: PROJECT_NAME/src/main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml: null: Successfully released change log lock
```

Which suggests me that it has found my properties file and ran it successfully (the database is updated as well).

However, the command fails with this reason:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.0.5:update (default-cli) on project PROJECT_NAME: Failed to resolve the properties file. -> [Help 1]
```

(And, this being Java, Help 1 is no help at all. All it says it's a MojoFailureException, of course.)

My POM has this as a dependency:

```
<!-- Liquid Base -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

And this is where I configure the plugin:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <propertyFile>PROJECT_NAME/src/main/resources/db/changelog/liquibase.yaml</propertyFile>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

On my liquibase.yaml file:

```
driver: org.postgresql.Driver
classpath: ./lib/postgresql-9.2-1002-jdbc4.jar
url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/ifood_extranet_bff
username: xxx
password: xxx
changeLogFile: PATH_NAME/src/main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml
```

On the db.changelog-master.yaml:

```
databaseChangeLog:
- include:
    file: extranet-bff-core/src/main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-1.0.yaml
```

And db.changelog-1.0.yaml:
    ---
    databaseChangeLog:
     - changeSet:
        id: 1
        author: matheus.serpellone
        changes:
          - createTable:
              tableName: PERMISSIONS
              columns:
                - column:
                    name: ID
                    type: bigint
                    autoIncrement: true
                    constraints:
                      primaryKey: true
                      nullable: false
                - column:
                    name: ROLE
                    type: Varchar(255)
                    constraints:
                      nullable: false
                - column:
                    name: PERMISSION
                    type: Varchar(255)
                    constraints:
                      nullable: false
    ...

So... what could be giving the "Failed to resolve properties file?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, the probem was: I was trying to configure the plugin on my root pom.xml, but I also had two submodules. One had the liquibase.yaml file, the other didn't.

That way, when I ran `mvn liquibase:update` on the parent project, it would successfully run the migration on the first module but would fail on the second, giving me the output above...